# Portable Redux Components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have written a redux component that I want to use in two different apps.

However, many of my action generators require knowledge of information that is currently passed down via props. It's a fairly deep component, so there's a lot of long prop chains, etc.

What I'd love to do is to load this information into the redux store instead, so that my actions can fetch it from `getState` via `redux-thunk`.

Eg

```
export const updateSomething = (something) => (dispatch, getState) => dispatch({
  type: UPDATE_SOMETHING,
  preferences: getState().entities.users[getState().ui.selectedUserId].preferences,
  something,
})
```

However, **the state shape in my two apps is (necessarily) different**. Hence writing these actions with `getState` to fit one app means it doesn't work in another. For example, perhaps the other app uses the key `members` instead of `users` in the state.

Instead I have the aforementioned deep chains of props, and having to pass in lots of arguments to my action calls, which I'd love to just keep in the store (instead of calls like `(something) => updateSomething(something, preferences, someData, otherInfo`).

Is there a consensus on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You say "share the component", do you want to share the actions as well?

Comment: Maybe you have some selectors in both apps, which you can pass to action creator to get data from the right place.